# Android App - what are biggest reasons for slow mp3 downloads

Tags: android

For an Android app in development, mp3 download times from a 3rd party server are up to 200% slower than downloading the same mp3 (from same 3rd party server) using several other existing apps. There is no processing being done against the mp3 file during or post-download...rather, it's just a straightforward download. Testing was done on a Samsung Galaxy device running Android 4.0, with 1 gig RAM.

Aside from using the wrong buffer rate (which as I understand it from reading other questions on StackOverflow determines how often to write from cache to the internal SD card), what are the biggest red flags that we should look for or biggest mistakes we are likely making that are causing our downloads to be so much slower than other apps?

Thank you for any help!

Comment: It is possible that the slow speed is a result of something entirely unrelated happening in your app pegging the CPU. Can you post a stripped down app with just the download code that seems to have the issue you describe?

Comment: It would be interesting to route the comparison cases through a wifi network you can packet sniff.

Comment: @Evan I can tell you that based on the Android device's "developer options" in the device settings, I can see that the CPU is not pegged. The CPU usage isn't significantly different between our app and the other apps for which the same mp3 file download (from same 3rd party server) occurs much faster.

Comment: @ChrisStratton I do agree that our internet connection could be getting throttled, but we have done our best to control for that by changing up the order and time between our tests of our app and other existing apps.....and repeating the test on different WiFi networks (different locations).

Comment: I was meaning so that you could see if they were doing something differently - different packet sizes, parallel downloads, or maybe discover something suboptimal about your own.

Comment: @ChrisStratton ahhh...ok. That would be interesting information to know. I had hoped that there were a few common code mistakes along the lines of the "improper buffer size" that we might be getting wrong. Any come to mind?

Answer (score 0):

For our application, we found that optimizing the buffer size was sufficient to bring our MP3 download speed up to (and, in some cases, better than) other existing apps when we tested the download time for the same mp3 file from the same 3rd party server on several different WiFi networks.

I hope this helps other developers should they ever confront this same issue. CHEERS!